# MySQL Join with many (fields) to one (secondary table) relationship

Tags: mysql, join

I have a query I need to perform on a table that is roughly 1M records.  I am trying to reduce the churn, but unfortunately there is a UNION involved (after i figure this join out), so that may be a question for another day.

The records and data I need to get reference 3 fields in a table that need each pull a description from another table and return it in the same record, but when i do the Inner join i was thinking, it either returns only 1 field fromt he other table, or multiple records from  he original table.

Here are some screen shots of the tables and their relationship:

**Primary table containing records (1 each) with the physician record I want to pull, including up to 3 codes that can be listed in the "taxonomy" table.**

[image: Primary Table]

**Secondary table containing records (1 each) with the "Practice" field I want to pull.**

[image: Secondary Tabke]

**A Quick glance of the relationship i'm talking about**

[image]

I presume that if perform an inner join matching the 3 fields in the physicians table, that it will have to iterate that table multiple times to pull each taxonomy code .. but I still can't even figure the syntax to easily pull all of these codes instead of just 1 of them.

i've tried this:

```
SELECT
taxonomy_codes.specialization,
physicians.provider_last_name,
physicians.provider_first_name,
physicians.provider_dba_name,
physicians.legal_biz_name,
physicians.biz_practice_city
FROM
taxonomy_codes
INNER JOIN physicians ON physicians.provider_taxonomy_code_1 = taxonomy_codes.taxonomy_codes OR physicians.provider_taxonomy_code_2 = taxonomy_codes.taxonomy_codes OR physicians.provider_taxonomy_code_3 = taxonomy_codes.taxonomy_codes
```

First, the query churns a lot and it only returns one taxonomy specialty result which I presume is because of the OR in the join statement. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you,

Silver Tiger

Comment: you'd be much better using a join table for your `provider_taxonomy_code` columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to join the taxonomy_codes table multiple times:

```
SELECT p.provider_last_name, p...., t1.specialization as specialization1, t2.specialization as specialization2, t3.specialization as specialization3
FROM physicians p
LEFT JOIN taxonomy_codes t1 ON t1.taxonomy_codes = provider_taxonomy_code_1
LEFT JOIN taxonomy_codes t2 ON t2.taxonomy_codes = provider_taxonomy_code_2
LEFT JOIN taxonomy_codes t3 ON t3.taxonomy_codes = provider_taxonomy_code_3
```

Comment: ill try to do that and let you know how it goes, much appreciated

Comment: Worked like a charm, though the query was 42 seconds sadly. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Make sure that you have an index on taxonomy_codes.taxonomy_codes

Comment: nm, I had not included a filter Where cluase - after adding a level or two of clarification, i got the query down to between 2 and 4 seconds with a limit of 100 .. thx